# Blank page after modification on code of 3D map exported from qgis2threejs

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I need to change some code inside a 3D map created with qgis2threejs the QGIS's plugin for 3D webmap.

I'm not an expert to threejs library and  javascript. I want do change this

```
    // load the scene
    app.loadJSONFile(
            "./data/index/scene.json",
            function () {
              app.start();
              // North arrow inset
              if (Q3D.Config.northArrow.visible) app.buildNorthArrow(document.getElementById("northarrow"), app.scene.userData.rotation);
            }
          );
```

To include scene.json instead of his path. I want to use this code:

```
// load the scene
app.loadJSONFile(
        {"type": "scene", "properties": {"height": 90.1010101010101, "width": 100.0, "baseExtent": [725282.3732700318, 6006086.588087205, 727901.7482727035, 6008446.671422945], "crs": "EPSG:3857", "proj": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs", "rotation": 0, "wgs84Center": {"lat": 47.39790958284822, "lon": 6.527087535108197}, "zExaggeration": 1.0, "zShift": 0.0}, "layers": [{"type": "layer", "id": 0, "properties": {"name": "clip_dtm_francia_eudem", "queryable": 1, "visible": true, "type": "dem", "shading": true}, "data": [{"type": "block", "layer": 0, "block": 0, "grid": {"width": 211, "height": 190, "url": "./data/index/a0.bin"}, "width": 100.0, "height": 90.1010101010101, "translate": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "zShift": 0.0, "zScale": 0.038177046012121664, "material": {"type": 0, "image": {"url": "./data/index/a0.png"}, "ds": 1}, "sides": true}]}]},
        function () {
          app.start();
          // North arrow inset
          if (Q3D.Config.northArrow.visible) app.buildNorthArrow(document.getElementById("northarrow"), app.scene.userData.rotation);
        }
      );
```

This is all the code of scene.json. When I do this the 3D become blank but inside Developers tool of Chrome there isn't any errors.

How I can solve this problem? If you want to see all the code you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bX7nllS31uD8SBFTQq4NEcwF5bxwbD7x)(2MB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `loadJSONFile()` try it with `loadJSONObject()`. Notice that the method has no callback parameter so the new code should look like so:

```
app.loadJSONObject( {"type": "scene", "properties": {"height": 90.1010101010101, "width": 100.0, "baseExtent": [725282.3732700318, 6006086.588087205, 727901.7482727035, 6008446.671422945], "crs": "EPSG:3857", "proj": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs", "rotation": 0, "wgs84Center": {"lat": 47.39790958284822, "lon": 6.527087535108197}, "zExaggeration": 1.0, "zShift": 0.0}, "layers": [{"type": "layer", "id": 0, "properties": {"name": "clip_dtm_francia_eudem", "queryable": 1, "visible": true, "type": "dem", "shading": true}, "data": [{"type": "block", "layer": 0, "block": 0, "grid": {"width": 211, "height": 190, "url": "./data/index/a0.bin"}, "width": 100.0, "height": 90.1010101010101, "translate": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "zShift": 0.0, "zScale": 0.038177046012121664, "material": {"type": 0, "image": {"url": "./data/index/a0.png"}, "ds": 1}, "sides": true}]}]} );
app.start();
if (Q3D.Config.northArrow.visible) app.buildNorthArrow(document.getElementById("northarrow"), app.scene.userData.rotation);
```